# How to call .ashx handler from WPF Application?

Tags: .net, wpf, ashx

I have .ashx generic handler on server and I want to call it from WPF application to retrieve some information, is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the System.Net.WebClient class to access a URL.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0)" +
    " (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

    // Download data.
    byte[] arr = client.DownloadData("http://www.yourserver.com/"); // url for .ashx file

    // Write values.
    Console.WriteLine("--- WebClient result ---");
    Console.WriteLine(arr.Length);

}
```

Here you can find the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).